# How to properly update URLs in Next.js? (Error: Loading initial props cancelled)

Tags: next.js

If I type too quickly in a search bar that updates the url to trigger getServerSideProps, I start seeing "Error: Loading initial props cancelled". It makes me wander if I'm supposed to use shallow routing so that getServerSideProps is not triggered, and instead use a fetch request to an api route.

I found [this comment](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/21073#discussioncomment-3855328) which seems to indicate this is simply a bug when using router.push on the same route.

*chrome console after typing aaaaaaaaaaaaaa*

```
next-dev.js?3515:20 Error: Loading initial props cancelled
    at eval (router.js?8684:1514:29)
window.console.error    @   next-dev.js?3515:20
overrideMethod  @   react_devtools_backend.js:4012
eval    @   router.js?8684:1064
asyncGeneratorStep  @   _async_to_generator.js?0e30:13
_next   @   _async_to_generator.js?0e30:31
eval    @   _async_to_generator.js?0e30:36
eval    @   _async_to_generator.js?0e30:28
handleRouteInfoError    @   router.js?8684:1110
eval    @   router.js?8684:1299
asyncGeneratorStep  @   _async_to_generator.js?0e30:13
_throw  @   _async_to_generator.js?0e30:34
Promise.then (async)        
asyncGeneratorStep  @   _async_to_generator.js?0e30:22
_next   @   _async_to_generator.js?0e30:31
Promise.then (async)        
asyncGeneratorStep  @   _async_to_generator.js?0e30:22
_next   @   _async_to_generator.js?0e30:31
Promise.then (async)        
asyncGeneratorStep  @   _async_to_generator.js?0e30:22
_next   @   _async_to_generator.js?0e30:31
eval    @   _async_to_generator.js?0e30:36
eval    @   _async_to_generator.js?0e30:28
getRouteInfo    @   router.js?8684:1301
eval    @   router.js?8684:821
asyncGeneratorStep  @   _async_to_generator.js?0e30:13
_next   @   _async_to_generator.js?0e30:31
Promise.then (async)        
asyncGeneratorStep  @   _async_to_generator.js?0e30:22
_next   @   _async_to_generator.js?0e30:31
Promise.then (async)        
asyncGeneratorStep  @   _async_to_generator.js?0e30:22
_next   @   _async_to_generator.js?0e30:31
eval    @   _async_to_generator.js?0e30:36
eval    @   _async_to_generator.js?0e30:28
change  @   router.js?8684:1034
push    @   router.js?8684:560
instance.<computed> @   router.js?31fc:147
eval    @   SearchBar.tsx?217d:54
commitHookEffectListMount   @   react-dom.development.js?ac89:23150
commitPassiveMountOnFiber   @   react-dom.development.js?ac89:24926
commitPassiveMountEffects_complete  @   react-dom.development.js?ac89:24891
commitPassiveMountEffects_begin @   react-dom.development.js?ac89:24878
commitPassiveMountEffects   @   react-dom.development.js?ac89:24866
flushPassiveEffectsImpl @   react-dom.development.js?ac89:27039
flushPassiveEffects @   react-dom.development.js?ac89:26984
commitRootImpl  @   react-dom.development.js?ac89:26935
commitRoot  @   react-dom.development.js?ac89:26682
performSyncWorkOnRoot   @   react-dom.development.js?ac89:26117
flushSyncCallbacks  @   react-dom.development.js?ac89:12042
flushSync   @   react-dom.development.js?ac89:26201
finishEventHandler  @   react-dom.development.js?ac89:3976
batchedUpdates  @   react-dom.development.js?ac89:3994
dispatchEventForPluginEventSystem   @   react-dom.development.js?ac89:9287
dispatchEventWithEnableCapturePhaseSelectiveHydrationWithoutDiscreteEventReplay @   react-dom.development.js?ac89:6465
dispatchEvent   @   react-dom.development.js?ac89:6457
dispatchDiscreteEvent
```

Eventually after typing more or holding down a key, I get "SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'measure' on 'Performance': The mark 'beforeRender' does not exist."

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'measure' on 'Performance': The mark 'beforeRender' does not exist.
    at markRenderComplete (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/client/index.js:313:17)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/client/index.js:350:70)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/client/index.js:350:50)
    at commitHookEffectListMount (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:23145:26)
    at commitLayoutEffectOnFiber (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:23263:17)
    at commitLayoutMountEffects_complete (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:24683:9)
    at commitLayoutEffects_begin (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:24669:7)
    at commitLayoutEffects (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:24607:3)
    at commitRootImpl (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:26818:5)
    at commitRoot (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:26677:5)
    at finishConcurrentRender (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:25976:9)
    at performConcurrentWorkOnRoot (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:25804:7)
    at workLoop (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/scheduler/cjs/scheduler.development.js:266:34)
    at flushWork (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/scheduler/cjs/scheduler.development.js:239:14)
    at MessagePort.performWorkUntilDeadline (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/scheduler/cjs/scheduler.development.js:533:21)
```

*search bar*

```
export function parseQueryString(string: string | string[] | undefined) { //helper method
  if (typeof string === 'string') {
    return string
  }
}

  const router = useRouter()
  const [search, setSearch] = useState(
    parseQueryString(router.query.search) ?? ''
  )

  useEffect(() => {
    if (search) {
      router.push({ query: { ...router.query, search } })
    } else {
      const { query } = router
      delete query.search
      router.push({ query })
    }
  }, [search])
```

*home page*

```
export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps<Props> = async (
  context
) => {
  const { page } = context.query

  const skip = (parseQueryInt(page, 1) - 1) * NUM_ITEMS_PER_PAGE
  const search = parseQueryString(context.query.search)
    ?.split(' ')
    .filter((i) => i) //empty strings are falsy and will be filtered out so you don't get "word1 " => "word1 & "
    .join(' & ') // "word1 word2" becomes "word1 & word2" which respects postgresql syntax

  const numPages = Math.ceil(
    (await prisma.product.count({
      where: {
        title: { search },
      },
    })) / NUM_ITEMS_PER_PAGE
  )

  const products = await prisma.product.findMany({
    skip,
    take: NUM_ITEMS_PER_PAGE,
    where: {
      title: {
        search,
      },
    },
  })
  return {
    props: {
      products,
      numPages,
    },
  }
}
```

[full code](https://github.com/bogdan-pechounov/next-prisma/commit/2b693d8153f57dc3819ad8bd2ff8e23ac996bf6b)